# Rice grain Segmentation in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-segmentation

I have an image of multiple rice grains in jpg format. I need to separate the individual rice grains into a separate images.
The input image is as below:

[image]

The resultant images should contain individual rice as below:

[image]

Currently I am using the following code:

```
close all;

BW = imread('img11_Inp','jpg');
L = bwlabel(BW)

figure
    imshow(BW);
CC = bwconncomp(L);
stats = regionprops(L,'Image');
stats

%Display the first component as an image
Image1 = stats(2).Image
figure
    imshow(Image1);
```

There are two problems with this code. Firstly, it is showing only two images rice grains in the "stats" structure and secondly it is also showing some noise. Please let me know what is the problem with this code

Answer (score 1):

Look at this code with the comments

```
close all;
clear

I = imread('rice.jpg'); % jpg add noise. TODO: use png format
level = graythresh(I); % Global image threshold using Otsu's method
BW1 = imbinarize(I,level); % need to threshold, jpg add low level noise.
BW2 = imfill(BW1,'holes'); %fill holes inside grains

[L,n] = bwlabel(BW2); % label connected components
B = labeloverlay(I,L); 
figure('Name',sprintf('NLables=%d',n)); imshow(B);

stats = regionprops(L,{'Centroid','Area'});
for i=1:length(stats)
    x=stats.Centroid(i,1);
    y=stats.Centroid(i,2);
    area=stats.Area(i);
    text(x,y,sprintf('Area=%d',area),'FontSize',8);
end
```

Comment: It would be good if you posted the original image as well as your segmented version for comparison.

Comment: @kkuilla, i used the image in the question. with chrome browser you can save it with right click "save image as.." and rename it to "rice.jpg"